# Largest k elements in array under contraints

Tags: data-structures

Given an array of integers, how can I print the largest k elements in O(k) ?
Important : the array is initialized with zeros. whenever the program calls a function `Add(i)` the i'th cell is incremented by ***1*** . How can I make use of this fact in order to maintain order inside the array before calling the print function?

Space complexity needed : O(n), where n is the size of the given array.
I'm looking for a solution that dosen't involve heaps.

Comment: *"I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve heaps."* And why don't you want to use a heap?

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution that works by using lots and lots of linked lists.

The basic idea is the following. For each array location, make a doubly-linked list cell representing that array element. Then, group all the elements in the array by their numeric value. For example, when you first create the array and everything has value zero, you'd have a doubly-linked list of all the array locations, like this:

```
+---+     +---+     +---+     +---+     +---+
| 0 | <-> | 1 | <-> | 2 | <-> | 3 | <-> | 4 |
+---+     +---+     +---+     +---+     +---+
```

Whenever you increment a value by one, splice it out of the list it's in and add it to a new list representing values that are one greater than the previous value. For example, incrementing array index 3 would make things look like this:

```
                   +---+     +---+     +---+     +---+
Cells with value 0 | 0 | <-> | 1 | <-> | 2 | <-> | 4 |
                   +---+     +---+     +---+     +---+

                   +---+
Cells with value 1 | 3 |
                   +---+
```

Incrementing cell 2 would then give this:

```
                   +---+     +---+     +---+
Cells with value 0 | 0 | <-> | 1 | <-> | 4 |
                   +---+     +---+     +---+

                   +---+     +---+
Cells with value 1 | 2 | <-> | 3 |
                   +---+     +---+
```

Incrementing cell 3 again would then give this:

```
                   +---+     +---+     +---+
Cells with value 0 | 0 | <-> | 1 | <-> | 4 |
                   +---+     +---+     +---+

                   +---+
Cells with value 1 | 2 |
                   +---+

                   +---+
Cells with value 2 | 3 |
                   +---+
```

Now, suppose you incremented cell (2) again. This would move cell (2) into the linked list for cells with value 2. Since the list for cells with value (1) is no longer needed, we can just delete it:

```
                   +---+     +---+     +---+
Cells with value 0 | 0 | <-> | 1 | <-> | 4 |
                   +---+     +---+     +---+

                   +---+     +---+
Cells with value 2 | 2 | <-> | 3 |
                   +---+     +---+
```

To increment 0, we'd then recreate the list of value 1, as shown here:

```
                   +---+     +---+
Cells with value 0 | 1 | <-> | 4 |
                   +---+     +---+

                   +---+
Cells with value 1 | 0 |
                   +---+

                   +---+     +---+
Cells with value 2 | 2 | <-> | 3 |
                   +---+     +---+
```

To print out the top k elements in time O(k), you start at the highest-value linked list and print out the elements there. If that wasn't enough, then go to the second-highest-value list and print its contents, then the next list, then the next, etc.

The challenge is how to maintain these separate linked lists. We need to be able to do the following:

1. Determine which linked list a particular cell is in, so that we can bump it up to the next level.
2. Determine what numeric value is associated with a particular linked list, so that when we promote one cell to a higher value we can determine whether to move it to the next list in the series or whether we need to create a new list.
3. Remove an empty list whose value is no longer in use.
4. Iterate over the lists backwards, so we can print the top k elements.

One solution to this problem is to represent the list of lists using *another* doubly-linked list. Specifically, we'll do the following:

- Maintain a doubly-linked list of lists. Each cell in the "list of lists" will store the number associated with the cells in that list.
- Maintain a pointer to the last cell in the "list of lists" so that we can efficiently print the top k elements.
- Annotate each existing cell with a pointer to the "list of lists" cell so that, when we do an increment, we can determine which list it belongs to.

For example, what I've been drawing like this:

```
                   +---+     +---+
Cells with value 0 | 1 | <-> | 4 |
                   +---+     +---+

                   +---+
Cells with value 1 | 0 |
                   +---+

                   +---+     +---+
Cells with value 2 | 2 | <-> | 3 |
                   +---+     +---+
```

Would actually look like this:

```
                   +--------+---------+
                   |        |         | 
                   v        |         |
+--------------------+    +---+     +---+
| Cells with value 0 | -> | 1 | <-> | 4 |
+--------------------+    +---+     +---+
          ^
          |   +-------------+
          |   |             |
          v   v             |
+--------------------+    +---+
| Cells with value 1 | -> | 0 |
+--------------------+    +---+
          ^
          |        +--------+---------+
          |        |        |         | 
          v        v        |         |
+--------------------+    +---+     +---+
| Cells with value 2 | -> | 2 | <-> | 3 |
+--------------------+    +---+     +---+
          ^
          |
          +---- max
```

This allows us to splice elements out of a list, figure out which list they belong to, then determine whether to splice them into the list above us or whether to create a new list between the two lists.

Each element in the array uses space O(1) on its own. Each "list of lists" cell takes space O(1) and there are at most n of them because there's one per value stored. Each increment takes time O(1), and the top k elements can be found in time O(k) by walking backwards from the end of the "list of lists" and printing out values. And no heaps were harmed in the making of this data structure. :-)

Hope this helps!